# What does return mean in Python?

Tags: python, return

I searched the whole internet for the meaning of the `return` statement.

I know it ends the define statement, but I know it still does something else!

What else does it do?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is easily found by googling "return python"

Comment: In Python 2, [`return` returns a value from a function](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement). That's all it does. In Python 3, it can also return values from generators.

Comment: It means the same thing it means in all other programming languages that have a return statement. This is not at all specific to python; and is also covered in just about every introductory programming tutorial that deals with functions.

Answer (score 9):

It `returns` the flow of control to the calling function. It also `returns` output/results to the calling function.

Consider the function below:

```
def am_i_wrong(answer):
    if answer == 'yes':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You have multiple returns. So `return` doesn't simply end the function definition. It instead is the point at which the function returns the result to the caller.

If `answer` is equal to 'yes' then anything after the if statement (after if and else) is never run because the function has already returned.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) explain fully how a return function works. Its also the first answer in the google query **python return**...

Comment: if this guy is asking about the return statement then I don't think the docs would help.

the docs seem to be a reference of python syntax to people who already know and understand python. it's not for newbies