# Returning list of words counted on different list

Tags: python, string, count, notepad++, python-3.5

Good afternoon guys,

Today i have been asked to write the following function:

```
def compareurl(url1,url2,enc,n)
```

This function compares two urls and return a list containing:

```
[word,occ_in_url1,occ_in_u2]
```

where:

word ---> word with n lenght

occ_in_url1 ---> times word in url1

occ_in_url2 ---> times word in url2

So I started writing the function, this is what i have wrote so far:

```
def compare_url(url1,url2,enc,n):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    with urlopen('url1') as f1:
        readpage1 = f1.read()
        decodepage1 = readpage1.decode('enc')
    with urlopen('url2') as f2:
        readpage2 = f2.read()
        decodepage2 = readpage2.decode('enc')
    all_lower1 = decodepage1.lower()
    all_lower2 = decodepage2.lower()
    import string
    all_lower1nopunctuation = "".join(l for l in all_lower1 if l not in string.punctuation)
    all_lower2nopunctuation = "".join(l for l in all_lower2 if l not in string.punctuation)
    for word1 in all_lower1nopunctuation:
        if len(word1) == k:
            all_lower1nopunctuation.count(word1)
    for word2 in all_lower2nopunctuation:
        if len(word2) == k:
            all_lower2opunctuation.count(word2)
    return(word1,all_lower1nopunctuation.count(word1),all_lower2opunctuation.count(word2))
    return(word2,all_lower1nopunctuation.count(word1),all_lower2opunctuation.count(word2))
```

But this code doesn't work in the way I thought, actually it doesn't work at all.

I would also like to:

1. sort the returning list decreasingly (from the word which return the most times)
2. if 2 words occurs the same number of times, they must be returned in 
   alphabetical order

Comment: what output error do you get?

Comment: ValueError: unknown url type: 'url1'                                                                  but this is only one of the errors, i don't manage to return the right thing

Comment: "with urlopen('url1') as f1:" url1 is a var, you are transforming it to string using single quote. It should be "with urlopen(url1) as f1:". Do the same for url2

Comment: The "k", as in "if len(word1) == k:", should be "n": "if len(word1) == n:"

Comment: i corrected those mistake, but the problem still remains

Comment: yeah, there are some other problems, i'll run your code and see if I can figure it out. Question though: "This function compares two urls and return a list containing", does it really need to return a list? I think a dictionary would be better

Comment: yes, the function must return a list :)

Comment: it will be a list of lists then, otherwise you are going to return only the FIRST (or the LAST) word that repeats on both urls. Is that right?

Comment: the function must return a list of tuples, where the tuple is made up of:    the word with given lenght, times word in url1  and times word in url2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typos in your code (watch out for those in the future) but there are some python problems (or things that can be improved) as well.

---

First of all, your [imports should come in the top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/128577/7067541) of the document

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import string
```

---

You should call `urlopen` with a `string`, and that's what you are doing, but this string is `'url1'` and not `'http://...'`. You don't use variables inside quotes:

```
with urlopen(url1) as f1: #remove quotes
    readpage1 = f1.read()
    decodepage1 = readpage1.decode(enc) #remove quotes
with urlopen(url2) as f2: #remove quotes
    readpage2 = f2.read()
    decodepage2 = readpage2.decode(enc) #remove quotes
```

---

You need to improve your **all_lower1nopunctuation** initialization. You are replacing `stackoverflow.com` with `stackoverflowcom`, which should actually be `stackoverflow com`.

```
#all_lower1nopunctuation = "".join(l for l in all_lower1 if l not in string.punctuation)
#the if statement should be after 'l' and before 'for'
#you should include 'else' to replace the punctuation with a space
all_lower1nopunctuation = ''.join(l if l not in string.punctuation
else ' ' for l in all_lower1)
all_lower2nopunctuation = ''.join(l if l not in string.punctuation
else ' ' for l in all_lower2)
```

---

Merge both `for` into one. Also add the found word in a set (list of unique elements).

`all_lower1nopunctuation.count(word1)` returns the number of times **word1** appears in **all_lower1nopunctuation**. It **doesn't** increment a counter.

`for word1 in all_lower1nopunctuation` doesn't work because **all_lower1nopunctuation** is a **string** (and not a **list**). Transform it into a **list** with `.split(' ')`.

`.replace('\n', '')` removes all line breaks, otherwise they would be counted as **words** too.

```
#for word1 in all_lower1nopunctuation:
#    if len(word1) == k: #also, this should be == n, not == k
#        all_lower1nopunctuation.count(word1)
#for word2 in all_lower2nopunctuation:
#    if len(word2) == k:
#        all_lower2opunctuation.count(word2)

word_set = set([])
for word in all_lower1nopunctuation.replace('\n', '').split(' '):
    if len(word) == n and word in all_lower2nopunctuation:
        word_set.add(word) #set uses .add() instead of .append()
```

---

Now that you have a set of words that appear on both urls, you need to store how many **word** is in each url.
The following code will ensure you have a **list of tuples** as [you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307662/returning-list-of-words-counted-on-different-list#comment67879052_40307662)

```
count_list = []
for final_word in word_set:
    count_list.append((final_word,
    all_lower1nopunctuation.count(final_word),
    all_lower2nopunctuation.count(final_word)))
```

---

> Returning means the function is finished and the interpreter continues wherever it was before the function was called, so whatever comes after the return is irrelevant.

As said by [RemcoGerlich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169204/using-two-return-statements-in-a-function-python-2-7).

Your code will always **only** return the **first** `return`, so you need to merge both returns into one.

```
#return(word1,all_lower1nopunctuation.count(word1),all_lower2opunctuation.count(word2))
#return(word2,all_lower1nopunctuation.count(word1),all_lower2opunctuation.count(word2))
return(count_list) # which contains a list of tuples with all words and its counts
```

---

**TL;DR**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import string

def compare_url(url1,url2,enc,n):
    with urlopen(url1) as f1:
        readpage1 = f1.read()
        decodepage1 = readpage1.decode(enc)
    with urlopen(url2) as f2:
        readpage2 = f2.read()
        decodepage2 = readpage2.decode(enc)

    all_lower1 = decodepage1.lower()
    all_lower2 = decodepage2.lower()

    all_lower1nopunctuation = ''.join(l if l not in string.punctuation
    else ' ' for l in all_lower1)
    all_lower2nopunctuation = ''.join(l if l not in string.punctuation
    else ' ' for l in all_lower2)

    word_set = set([])
    for word in all_lower1nopunctuation.replace('\n', '').split(' '):
        if len(word) == n and word in all_lower2nopunctuation:
            word_set.add(word)

    count_list = []
    for final_word in word_set:
        count_list.append((final_word,
        all_lower1nopunctuation.count(final_word),
        all_lower2nopunctuation.count(final_word)))

    return(count_list)

url1 = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm'
url2 = 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/128577/7067541'

for word_count in compare_url(url1,url2, 'utf-8', 5):
    print (word_count)
```

Comment: thank you so much :) it works like it should be; last thing: how can i sort the tuples in ascending order from the word which occurs the most?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10695161/7067541

Something like `return(sorted(count_list, key=lambda x: x[1] + x[2]))`

Comment: if 2 words occurs the same number of times, like: (word1,1,1) (word2,1,1) (word3,3,3) how do i return them in alphabetical order ? (keeping the descending order of times word occurs)

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe `sorted(sorted(count_list), key=lambda x: x[1] + x[2])`